# Covariance between functions of same $Z_k$ = 0

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, summation, covariance

Let's assume we are faced with showing that the following covariance between two functions $g(\cdot)$ and $f(\cdot)$ of the same set of $Z_1,...,Z_K$ i.i.d. standard normal random variables is equal to $0$ (we want to show that they are independent), such that:

$$Cov\left[f(Z_k),g(Z_k)\right]= Cov\left[\sqrt{\hat{\rho}_{s}}\hat{Y},\sum_{k=1}^K\left(\sqrt{\rho_{s}}\alpha_{s,k} -  \sqrt{\hat{\rho}_{s}}\beta_{k}\right)Z_k\right] = 0 $$
where $S=K$ and
$$\hat{Y} = \sum_{k=1}^K\beta_{k} Z_k \quad\;,\quad\; \sum_{k=1}^K\beta^2_{k} = 1 \quad\;,\quad\; \sum_{k=1}^K\alpha^2_{s,k}=1$$
Additionally, we know the following relationship between the parameters:
$$\sqrt{\hat{\rho}_{s}} = \sqrt{\rho_{s}}\sqrt{\gamma_{s}} = \sqrt{\rho_{s}}\sum_{k=1}^{K}\alpha_{s,k}\beta_k$$
consider that, overall, $\rho_{s},\gamma_{s},\hat{\rho}_{s},\alpha_{s,k},\beta_k$ are just model parameters.

I know that the above boils down to needing to show that (as all other covariances are 0):
$$Cov\left[f(Z_k)|g(Z_k)\right] = \left[\sqrt{\hat{\rho}_{s}}\sum_{k=1}^K\beta_{k} \times \sum_{k=1}^K\left(\sqrt{\rho_{s}}\alpha_{s,k} -  \sqrt{\hat{\rho}_{s}}\beta_{k}\right)\right] \underbrace{V[Z_k]}_{=1} = 0 $$

I have tried running the algebra a couple of times to show that the part inside the squared brackets $=0$ but was unable to reach that conclusion. Is there some properties of sums I am missing?

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall $\textrm{Cov}[X,Y]=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$. Note that $E[f]=E[g]=0$. If I understood correctly all the notation, we then have
$$\begin{aligned}E[fg]&=\sum_{k\leq K}\sum_{\ell\leq K}(\sqrt{\rho_s}\alpha_{s,k}-\sqrt{\hat{\rho}_s}\beta_k)\sqrt{\hat{\rho}_s}\beta_\ell E[Z_kZ_\ell]\\
&=\sum_{k\leq K}(\sqrt{\rho_s}\sqrt{\hat{\rho}_s}\alpha_{s,k}\beta_k-{\hat{\rho}_s}\beta_k^2)\\
&=\sqrt{\hat{\rho}_s}\bigg(\sqrt{\rho_s}\sum_{k\leq K}\alpha_{s,k}\beta_k\bigg)-\hat{\rho}_s\bigg(\sum_{k\leq K}\beta_k^2\bigg)\\
&=\hat{\rho}_s-\hat{\rho}_s\\\
&=0
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Snoop: I think you are perfectly right, I was investigating this path also at the moment. As when you go through the expectation, it is more evident that all the cross-terms cancel out and the double sum can be simplified to a single sum. Let me just double-check once more :)

Comment: Snoop: Basci question, do you agree that in this setup we have that $\hat{Y}$ and $Z_k$ are all $N(0,1)$. Hence, they follow a standard multivariate normal distribution, while $X=f(Z_k)$ and $Y=g(Z_k)$ are not $N(0,1)$, precisely, their variance is different from $1$. Hence, $(X,Y)$ follow a joint normal distribution (not standard) ?

Comment: @BMBE to allow for completeness and clarity in an answer to that, I would suggest posting another question asking specifically for the joint and marginals of the variables involved :)

Comment: Snoop: I will do that as soon as I can :) thanks !